# how to add checkbox to a button in a loop in kivy python

Tags: python, kivy

i am trying to add checkboxes to buttons from a loop. i need the checkbox to select the button should incase the user wish to delete a file. each buttons hold a file. here is my code:

```
Class FolderScreen(Screen):
  def on_enter(self, *args):
    #if self.nd == []:
    objf = mm.Storenote()
    objf.tif(mm.DB.hod)
    for i in range(len(mm.Storenote.ht)):
        self.b = Button(text= (mm.Storenote.ht[i]), font_size = "25sp")
        self.ck = CheckBox()
        self.b.add_widget(self.ck)
        #self.b.background_normal = ""
        self.b.background_color = 0,0,1,1
        self.b.ids =  {"id":mm.Storenote.nid[i]}
        self.b.size_hint=(1, None)
        self.b.size = (dp(370), dp(50))
        self.nd.append(self.b)
        self.b.bind(on_press=self.build_clickk(self.b))
        self.ids.lpl.add_widget(self.b)
```

The above code only create one checkbox that is position in the middle of the screen and not associated to any button. How to I create the checkboxes with the button in the same loop?

Comment: Try packing them together within a layout, maybe a `BoxLayout`.

Comment: The button is added to a box layout. the lpl  in the self.ids.lpl.add_widget(self.b) is the id  for the boxlayout

Answer (score 0):

The code you've provided is not runnable. That's why it's very hard to guess what's going on actually in your code.

However, following is a simple implementation for:

> i need the checkbox to select the button should incase the user wish to delete a file. each buttons hold a file...

```py
from kivy.app import runTouchApp
from kivy.properties import (BooleanProperty, StringProperty)
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox


class CustomButton(BoxLayout):
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    text = StringProperty("Check to select/deselect me")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.btn = Button(text = self.text)
        self.chbox = CheckBox()
        self.chbox.bind(active=self.setter("selected"))
        self.add_widget(self.chbox)
        self.add_widget(self.btn)
        self.bind(text=self.btn.setter("text"))
        
        self.chbox.bind(active=self.observe_change) # This is redundant, just to demonstrate the state-change. You can remove or modify it.


    def observe_change(self, *args):
        v = self.selected
        self.text = "Selected" if v else "Not selected"
        self.btn.background_color = (1, 1-v, 1-v, 1)
        print(self.selected)


runTouchApp(CustomButton())
```

Now you can add this `CustomButton` to any widget and remove it depending on its prop. `selected`.

Comment: I will try and see how I can adapt your code to mine and see if it will work. But my above code runs fine. The folderscreen class has a boxlayout class that is inside it in kivy. The boxlayout class from kivy has the Id lpl. I created the loop by adding the button widget to the boxlayout with the ID lpl.